# Annotate ebproofs premises and conclusions

Tags: annotations, ebproof

I want to annotate an ebproof proof tree on the left with a curly brace and some text, like in this picture:

[image]

I would usually do this with a `\text{Premises} \left\{ ... \right.`, but I can't figure out how to do this for the two parts of the proof tree (which must be in the same `prooftree` environment). What I **don't** want is having the annotation as part of the premise or conclusion, as then the proof tree separator would go between the annotations (as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337000/how-can-i-type-a-piecewise-function-inside-ebproofs-prooftree-environment) question).

Is this possible with the ebproof package or how would you go about typesetting something like this?

What I have right now:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{\text{Premises} \left\{ G; L \vdash e : \code{bool} \right.}
    \hypo{G; L; \texttt{rt} \vdash s_1}
    \hypo{G; L; \texttt{rt} \vdash s_2}
    \infer{3}[\textsc{If\_Else}]{\text{Conclusion} \left\{ G; L; \texttt{rt} \vdash \texttt{if $(e)$ $s_1$ else $s_2$} \right.}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

where I would like "Premises" and "Conclusions" to be left of the proof tree line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Looking at the manual of `ebproofs` I see nothing similar to your picture.

Comment: But isn't the top line understood to be the premises and the bottom line the conclusions? Why being redundant? Your readers *know* what you're talking about.

Comment: @egreg The point is to explain how inference rules work. It's for a cheatsheet for students.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\tikzmark`s, but maybe it is a bit too complicated in this context:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{ \tikzmark{top} \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
    \infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
    \hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
    \infer[left label=\tikzmark{mid}]2[app]{ \tikzmark{bot} \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    \coordinate (brace anchor) at ([xshift=-5pt, yshift=.75em]pic cs:top);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] 
        (brace anchor) -- ([yshift={.5ex+2pt}]brace anchor |- {pic cs:mid}) 
        node[left, midway, xshift=-5pt] {Premises};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] 
        ([yshift={.5ex-2pt}]brace anchor |- {pic cs:mid}) -- (brace anchor |- {pic cs:bot}) 
        node[left, midway, xshift=-5pt] {Conclusion};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it will do for now! Just wondering if it could be achieved more easily with e.g. a different proof tree package? Or for simple single-premise, single-conclusion rules, maybe do the thing entirely in tikz?